# How to block all other referer except localhost in web.confg

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-7

I have added a Rule to prevent referer spam in my web.config. but i want to allow only localhost and block all other referers in the same. Here is what i am trying but it is not working.

enter code here

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="abort referer spam requests" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^localhost:49363$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="^localhost:49363$"  />
                </conditions>
                <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-very-common-mistakes-when-using-iis-url-rewrite-module-a2ab7e4fee59 Mistake 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this rule.

This rule will just allow null reference or localhost and block request referenced from other domain.

```
        <rule name="abort rule" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_REFERER}" pattern="(^$|localhost)" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
```